# file_exists() and file_get_contents() fail on a file which is on a mounted network drive

Tags: php, windows, file, filesystems, nfs

Pretty self explanatory. For example, the file (AB.txt) is on both my C drive and my (NFS) mounted W drive. Windows 7 x64 operating system btw.

```
function fileExists($path){
     return (@fopen($path,"r")==true);
 }

var_dump(fileExists('C:\AB.txt'));
var_dump(fileExists('W:\AB.txt'));
var_dump(file_exists('C:\AB.txt'));
var_dump(file_exists('W:\AB.txt'));
```

Gives

> boolean true 
> dir='ltr'>boolean false
>
> boolean true
> dir='ltr'>boolean false

I can't find an explanation for this behavior on the php wiki, or when searching using Google.

Comment: What is `fileExists`? Also, have you tried `fopen`?

Comment: do you mean [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) or a custom function you made?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's in fact a custom function, added it's code. Just forgot to copy it.

Comment: why recreate an internal function (file_exists())? It will be slower

Comment: This function returns FALSE for files inaccessible due to safe mode restrictions and for symlinks pointing to non-existing files. Also check permission settings

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access a Windows Network Share you have to configure your WebServer with enough permissions for example:

```
$file = fopen("\\siscomx17\c\websapp.log",'r');
```

You will get an error telling you that the pathname doesnt exist this will be because Apache or IIS run as LocalSystem so you will have to enter to Services and configure Apache on "Open a session as" Create a new user that has enough permissions and also be sure that target share has the proper permissions.

Comment: As proven by this image: http://updo.nl/file/1798782d.png. The permission on the drive is 777. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Partly. But you can't access network shares with drive names, since the webserver (as with all servers) doesn't see mapped network drives. I'd suggest trying with FDQN

Comment: To clarify: Drive letters (like `W:\`) are per-user. Other users on the system, such as the web server, see a different set of drive letters which doesn't include your mapped servers.